# How to make up a regexp that matches all files in the directory except for files with .jar extension?

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

Let's assume that we have the next directory structure:

```
/parentdir/
   /childdir/
      child_file1.txt
      child_file2.jar  
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
```

so, we get next full file names:

```
/parentdir/file1.txt
/parentdir/file2.txt
/parentdir/childdir/child_file1.txt
/parentdir/childdir/child_file2.jar
```

Which regular expression matches all of these files except for the last one with .jar extension?

**Little clarification**: expression can contain 'parentdir' string and '.jar' string, all other files and directories can have any names and extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative assertions : `/(?<!\.jar)$/`

That would match anything that doesn't end in .jar

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. I use it in mercurials .hgignore file. Maybe, mercurial doesn't support this type of regex.

Comment: It's entirely possible, it's a Perl-compatible regular expression. I don't know mercurial or hgignore, so I can't help more, sorry!

Comment: It works, it just needs removing of the opening and closing slashes, e.g. "(?<!\.jar)".

Answer (score 1):

The negative assertion regex is one way to go, but the more common solution for this in mercurial land is to ignore broadly (for example just ignore `parentdir/`) and then `hg add` the few exception files you don't wanted ignored.

In svn and cvs you can't add a file that's in your ignore list and if you do future changes aren't tracked, but in mercurial `hg add` completely overrides ignore, so unless you'll have many new jars showing up in the future, just ignore broadly and add the .jar.

Comment: thanx, didn't know about this hg feature.